# Can I make a privacy policy on my own for free?

Tags: privacy, liability, digital-contract

I have the Problem that I want to start a web application which has access to the users files on dropbox and co. This involves saving some of the data local, e.g. the directory structure, access token, email addresses...

I know that I have to provide detailed information which data I save and how I use it. But I am a poor student who don't want invest money into a lawyer to write me a privacy policy (this is just a simple project which I want to share, I do not plan to get paid for it)

Is there any way I can do this privacy policy on my own?

Is it possible to just create some “I save all your data“ policy which would of course be to much but it would include all data I save and so I would not miss anything in my policy?

Does such a policy have to be in a specific form?

Comment: You can, but you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that I have to provide detailed information which data I save
>   and how I use it.

Yes, you should, if you are getting access to users' Dropbox accounts, which will contain all sorts of private data, copyrighted (and illegally copied copyrighted files), etc. You provide the detailed information to your users through a click-through Privacy Policy - TOS (Terms of Service) in your App, like any other App out there. [Click wrap (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_wrap) user agreements are legally binding in many jurisdictions.

Even if you don't access files and information - such as personal information or files - you still need a clear TOS for your App, for both your users' and your own legal protection.

> But I am a poor student who don't want invest money into a lawyer to
>   write me a privacy policy ... I do not plan to get paid for (this
>   app)...

Being a free or paid App doesn't make a difference when it comes to the TOS, if you need one, and if you need to pay for one to be drafted.

But not investing money in a lawyer can be a critical mistake if your App will be distributed on the popular App directories like Google Play and iTunes and your TOS does not clearly and legally outline all possible usage and data polices. Lawyers have experience in covering all the bases.

> Is there any way I can do this privacy policy on my own?

Sure, you can: https://www.google.com/search?q=privacy+policy+generator  But you run considerable legal liability not having a TOS that correctly and legally addresses all users' privacy concerns and clearly outlines what you do to insure security. That's what lawyers are for.

> Is it possible to just create some “I save all your data“ policy which
>   would of course be to much but it would include all data I save and so
>   I would not miss anything in my policy?

Sure, you can simply say *I save all your data.* But how can you be sure that you've haven't missed important policy details and scenarios that could result in legal action against you? Like *how long do you save data? When will you delete it? How secure is it? Can the user ask for deletion? What happens if you get hacked? What about users in countries other than the US? Users under 18 years old? You must use arbitration for any disputes?* And on and on.

The considerable legal liability of using a non-professionally drafted TOS means you run the risk of getting sued. You have to decide if it is worth the risk.

Comment: Many nations laws require specific things in privacy policies including deleting data on request - the policy may need to have different sections for different jurisdictions

Comment: @DaleM does this depend on the server location or something else?

Comment: @whymatter it depends on where the users are